# How to print ejs file data to pdf file using pdfkit in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Here is my result.ejs file code:

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SUBJECT</th>
                        <th>MARKS OBTAINED</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>pHYSICS</th>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Chemistry</th>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>mathematics</th>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>computer</th>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

In my user.js, I am rendring ejs file:

```
router.get("/result",async(req,res)=>{
  res.render("result");
})
```

I know basics about pdfkit. But I have used it for printing text only in pdf format like below:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const fs = require('fs');
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
doc
  .fontSize(25)
  .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);
```

**But Now I need to print ejs file table data in pdf format. Please help me to find out. Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. First you need to render the file and then pass it to pdf.  You simply need to render your ejs templated first and then pass the template string to filename `xyz.pdf` and you can see the ejs templated in pdf.

```
 // render the ejs file
  ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path-to-your-ejs'), data, {}, function(err, str) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);

    // str now contains your rendered html
   //your pdf object should be used here
    pdf.create(str).toFile("name of the file", function(err, data) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);

      res.send("File created successfully");
    });
  });
```

Referenced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360417/nodejs-how-to-generate-a-pdf-file-from-ejs-file) link, check the link for more info.

Comment: It is not working. I got error){
"errno": -4058,
"syscall": "open",
"code": "ENOENT",
"path": "C:\\Users\\91931\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2019\\views\\result.ejs"
}

Comment: You need to set the path and change the file name.

Comment: I have already changed file name. where to set path? Please help. pdf.create(str) // here pdf is simply) var pdf= require('html-pdf'); . I have written about pdf because maybe if there will be problem from package side..or I need to install more.

Comment: I have updated the comments in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much now its working. You saved me.

Comment: Please mark this question as accepted and upvote it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239011/discussion-between-balajee-mishra-and-apoorva-chikara).